# Python convert multi-column pandas dataframe to single value table dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to convert the following multi-level column pandas dataframe to single value table.

Initial table:

```
    Name    Monica          Rachel      
    Paper    1  2   3        1  2   3

2018-01-01  13  33  15      31  25  33
2018-06-01  11  43  30      36  23  37
```

New required dataframe table format:

```
Index        Name   Paper   Scores
2018-01-01  Monica    1       13
2018-01-01  Monica    2       33
2018-01-01  Monica    3       15
2018-06-01  Monica    1       11
2018-06-01  Monica    2       43
2018-06-01  Monica    3       30
2018-01-01  Rachel    1       31
2018-01-01  Rachel    2       25
2018-01-01  Rachel    3       33
2018-06-01  Rachel    1       36
2018-06-01  Rachel    2       23
2018-06-01  Rachel    3       37
```

I have tried 3 for loops, but could not replicate the Index values as many times.

Comment: What about unstack? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Comment: df.reset_index().melt('Index')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Wen stated use `melt`:

```
df.rename_axis('Index').reset_index().melt('Index', value_name='Score')
```

Output:

```
         Index Name Paper  Score
0   2018-01-01    m     1     13
1   2018-06-01    m     1     11
2   2018-01-01    m     2     33
3   2018-06-01    m     2     43
4   2018-01-01    m     3     15
5   2018-06-01    m     3     30
6   2018-01-01    r     1     31
7   2018-06-01    r     1     36
8   2018-01-01    r     2     25
9   2018-06-01    r     2     23
10  2018-01-01    r     3     33
11  2018-06-01    r     3     37
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `stack` and `reset_index`

```
df.rename_axis('Index').stack(['Name', 'Paper']).reset_index(name='Scores')

         Index    Name  Paper  Scores
0   2018-01-01  Monica      1      13
1   2018-01-01  Monica      2      33
2   2018-01-01  Monica      3      15
3   2018-01-01  Rachel      1      31
4   2018-01-01  Rachel      2      25
5   2018-01-01  Rachel      3      33
6   2018-06-01  Monica      1      11
7   2018-06-01  Monica      2      43
8   2018-06-01  Monica      3      30
9   2018-06-01  Rachel      1      36
10  2018-06-01  Rachel      2      23
11  2018-06-01  Rachel      3      37
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it into a Data Frame and then Group By Name and by Paper.

new_table = table.groupby(['Name', 'Paper'])]